# ASP.NET & Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009 how get data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

I want insert , update and delete  customer's table  in **Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009** helping ASP.NET , C#;
 **Passing by Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server;**
 Have anybody  C# code about this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Dynamics NAV Developer manual you'll find a chapter on how to work with web services. This also includes some examples on how to do your CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Web Reference and point it to the Web Services for NAV 2009.

Firstly, if you search "Web Services" in the top right, you need to expose the "Customer Card" page (Page 21).

Then in C# you need a web reference to connect to the SOAP web service.

Remember that if you UPDATE, you need to READ first.   When you call the UPDATE, there's a "key" field.  This field is passed in the UPDATE method call to ensure that you don't overwrite data if it is updated by another user.

Here's a good guide on adding a Web Reference. [Connecting to Nav with Web Reference](https://www.crt-insights.com/2018/08/15/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-c-using-web-reference/)